# Electron Forge with react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron-forge

Is there any simple way I can setup an app with Electron-Forge and React? I am usin the webpack template but don't know what to do to get jsx to work. I have the react stuff in renderer.js

Comment: Does this help ? https://ankitbko.github.io/2019/08/electron-forge-with-react-and-typescript/

Comment: Well, I didn't wan't to use typescript and I figured it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
    yarn create electron-app test --template=webpack
    cd test
```

Then I installed babel with:

```
    yarn add @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react --d
```

and react with:

```
    yarn add react react-dom
```

Created a .babelrc in project root with the following code:

```
    {"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]}
```

and added the following to webpack.rules.js:

```
    {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }
  }
```

changed renderer.js to renderer.jsx and changed stuff in package.json from this:

```
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
      {
        "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/index.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.js",
              "name": "main_window"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

to this:

```
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
      {
        "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/index.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.jsx",
              "name": "main_window"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

and finally replaced renderer.jsx with this:

```
    import './index.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    console.log('Loaded React.');
    ReactDOM.render(<div>Test.</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and replaced index.html with this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I followed your code and it works.  However, when I add sub-components and import (i.e. import Test from "./test";  It doesn't resolve the module unless I add ".jsx".  Did you have the same problem?

Comment: @Greg I am having the same problem. Did you find any solution for the same?

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy and @Greg no need just use `js` instead of `jsx`. Because he validate the regex pattern already `/\.(js|jsx)$/`. So use `js` for all  react file. And change the `webpack.rules.js` file to `renderer.js` instead of `renderer.jsx`. And don't forget `import React` for each react component file. Otherwise it will not show. better open devtools [mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsopendevtoolsoptions) on your main.js then do your code. myself it will more helpful to find this error

Comment: is itt using React-native-web also with the same step? Cause I have a existing  React-native-web in mobile. which to use this

Comment: not working with react 18 and electron forge 6

Answer (score 0):

1.Create Webpack template using

```
yarn create electron-app my-new-app --template=webpack && cd my-new-app
```

2.Install dependencies

```
yarn add --dev @babel/core @babel/preset-react babel-loader
```

3.Add the following to webpack.rules.js

```
 {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
```

4.Add React and React-dom

```
yarn add react react-dom
```

For more details refer [electron-forge](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react) documentation