# React Electron Forge not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm having a problem with integrating React and Electron Forge.
I followed this guide:
[Electron Forge with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62489701/electron-forge-with-react)
and it actually works, BUT it only works like this:

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout.jsx";
console.log('Loaded React.');
ReactDOM.render(<h1>hola</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I try to render a component it only shows a blank screen

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout.jsx";
console.log('Loaded React.');
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm using .jsx extension because it doesn't recognize it without it, which I think is a problem in webpack config or something like that BUT I know that is not the main problem, because I actually got this to work at some point xD and I dont remember exactly what I did.
So...that is not the problem but what should I do so that the component actually renders :'(?

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout.jsx";
console.log('Loaded React.');
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Expected it to render the component "Layout" but it shows blank screen.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: And the answer you use as reference is 3 years old, it's outdated and React has [deprecated `render` since v18](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/render). You should check the official docs.